# How to write NDEF message on NTag21X

Tags: nfc, ndef

I'm making an android NFC app using Mifare Classic tags. This app is working good.
However, not all Android device have a NXP NFC chip, some have a Broadcom NFC chip which does not support Mifare Classic tag.
So, for this kind of device I'm trying to use the NXP NTag213 or NTag216 tag which are supported by Broadcom NFC chip.
I used the "NXP TagInfo" app to try to read this kind of tag and in the techList the tag is known as [MifareUltralight-NfcA-Ndef-NdefFormatable].
I had a look on NXP datasheet and it stated that you can write data on NTag21X with Ndef format.
I can get an Ndef instance from my NTag but when I try to write my NdefMessage, everytime I get an IOException when I try to get the connexion by ndef.connect().

Do you have any idea why ?

Comment: I've just tested this with a Nexus S (NXP chipset) and a Nexus 5 (Broadcom chipset) and both succeed with connecting and writing  using the `Ndef` tag technology as well as with connecting and formatting using the `NdefFormatable` tag technology. However I did only have an NTAG210 so maybe that makes the difference... Nevertheless, could it be that you reach a timeout due to your debug setup or do you also get that exception when you run your application without a debugger being attached? Also what result do you get if you try to connect with the `NdefFormatable` tag technology?